# 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'index2word'

Tags: python-3.x, text-mining, word2vec

I'm getting this error "AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'index2word'" in following code in python. Anyone knows how can I solve it?
Acctually "tfidf_weighted_averaged_word_vectorizer" throws the error. "obli.csv" contains line of sentences. 
Thank you.

```
from feature_extractors import tfidf_weighted_averaged_word_vectorizer

    dataset = get_data2()
    corpus, labels = dataset.data, dataset.target
    corpus, labels = remove_empty_docs(corpus, labels)
    # print('Actual class label:', dataset.target_names[labels[10]])

    train_corpus, test_corpus, train_labels, test_labels = prepare_datasets(corpus,
                                                                            labels,
                                                                            test_data_proportion=0.3)
    tfidf_vectorizer, tfidf_train_features = tfidf_extractor(train_corpus)


    vocab = tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_
        tfidf_wv_train_features = tfidf_weighted_averaged_word_vectorizer(corpus=tokenized_train,
                                                                          tfidf_vectors=tfidf_train_features,
                                                                          tfidf_vocabulary=vocab,
                                                                          model=model,
                                                                          num_features=100)



    def get_data2():

        obli = pd.read_csv('db/obli.csv').values.ravel().tolist()
        cl0 = [0 for x in range(len(obli))]

        nonObli = pd.read_csv('db/nonObli.csv').values.ravel().tolist()
        cl1 = [1 for x in range(len(nonObli))]

        all = obli + nonObli


        db =  Db(all,cl0 + cl1)
        db.data = all
        db.target = cl0 + cl1

        return db
```

Comment: There's probably a bug in `tfidf_weighted_averaged_word_vectorizer()`. (It's likely based on an older version of gensim than you're using.) If you can describe where it's from, and show it's code, and possibly change its code, it may be possible to suggest a workaround. Also, when reporting Python errors, it's good to include the full 'error stack' you see in your question – which will show the actual line of code triggering the error, and the actual line calling that frame, etc – making it easier to see what's happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is code from chapter 4 of Text Analytics for Python by Dipanjan Sarkar.

index2word in gensim has been moved since that text was published.

Instead of `model.index2word` you should use `model.wv.index2word`.